# How to declare but not initialize a property in a Swift class

Tags: swift

```
class car {
    var oneWheel : Wheel
    func run(inputWheel:Wheel){
        oneWheel = inputWheel
        ....
    }
}
```

I don't want to implement init() and I don't want to initialize the wheel.

Comment: Declare it as optional, var oneWheel: Wheel?

Comment: Why don't you want to implement init? Are you anti-init?

Comment: Because I don't like a init(){} dangling in a class and does nothing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create an **implicitly unwrapped optional** - this will act like a normal variable but it does not need to be initialised - its initial value is `nil`. Just ensure the value is set before it is used otherwise you will get a fatal error for unwrapping nil.

```
class car {
  var oneWheel: Wheel!

  func run(inputWheel: Wheel) {
    wheel = inputWheel
  }
}
```

Comment: This works. But for someone who is clearly new to optionals, recommending that they use implicitly unwrapped optionals is sending them down a painful path of `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`

Answer (score 4):

Like so...

```
class car {
  var oneWheel : Wheel?
  // with this version, in order to pass oneWheel into this function as an argument, you will need to unwrap the optional value first. (see below example)
  func run(inputWheel:Wheel){
    oneWheel = inputWheel
    ....
  }
}
```

or if you would like the function to take an optional type `Wheel` as an argument do

```
class car {
   var oneWheel : Wheel?
   func run(inputWheel:Wheel?){
    //use conditional binding to safely unwrap the optional
    if let wheel = inputWheel {
    oneWheel = wheel
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

By using conditional binding, instead of an implicitly unwrapped optional, you avoid the potential of crashing due to... `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`, which occurs when the compiler finds nil where a non-nil value was expected.